# Java - print while getting input from another thread

Tags: java

I'm making a chat program where one thread is going to be printing messages from other users in `System.out`. At the same time, I'm going to be receiving input from `System.in` using a Scanner at the same time for the user to send a message. How can I make sure messages added will be before the user's input (and maybe a couple more characters before)?

Comment: "*At the same time, I'm going to be receiving input from System.out*" - Yo don't receive from `System.out`, you receive from `System.in`. The two channels do not interact, but the UX will be hindered: messages can be received while the user is typing. This has no effect on the functionality, but it is confusing as hell.

Comment: Yeah, that was an accident. I meant `System.in`.

Comment: Is this chat application for practice purposes or is it used in a web app/real time application?

Comment: Practical purposes and real time application? It's gonna run in the console.

Comment: Logically, how do you expect this to work? What will happen in the console if the user is typing a message and another user sends a message? You want it to interrupt your user's typing to display the new message? You can't somehow add a message in the console **above** the current line (on which the user is typing). At least not with `System.out`; you would need to create a new console-based UI yourself if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I originally thought there would be some way to print the text several lines back. I've seen this type of console work with other Java applications.